# Converting WCF services to GRPC or Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, grpc

We are currently in the process of rewriting our current Windows Forms applications that use WCF services for server side communication. Most of our methods uses Typed datasets for communication both ways, loading and saving from the client/server.

We are trying to find out whether GRPC or Web API (Asp.net Core/MVC controllers) support datasets for communication between client and server in both directions, and what is recommended.

I looked at web APIs, and the recommendation is to serialize/deserialize datasets to XML strings and load datasets from XML after getting the data. I couldn't find any good documents on GRPC. Any suggestions and recommendations?

Thanks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/typed-datasets

Comment: gRPC _typically_ uses protobuf, so you would normally convert from the datasets type into a protobuf representation.  But if there is any serialization of datasets to bytes (and back), then that can be used with gRPC instead.  The details of how to that would depend on your language, but at its core, gRPC is able to operate on bytes and not just protos.

Comment: Thanks I was able to convert the dataset to an XML string and pass it through GRPC and the Web API service, then load the dataset from the XML. I am not sure whether doing this is recommended or the correct approach. Other option is to just use generic collection like List of objects

Comment: That would work, but XML is probably not a very efficient encoding (both in space and conversion time), so if it's not performant enough, that's an obvious thing to optimize.